# simple text color in rich text box

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, colors

I can find a million examples of doing reg ex to apply syntax highlighting to a rich text box. but what i need it just a simple way to add in a word of a diffrent color.

What would the code be to just put the words "Hello World" into a textbox and have Hello be red and World be green?

This code doesnt work.

```
this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
this.richTextBox1.text += "Test"
```

Comment: It's tagged vb.net, and there are no semi-colons...

Comment: ...but then, the code uses this instead of Me... confusing!

Comment: Plus, `text` should be `Text`.

However, all of the OP's other .Net questions are VB, so I assume that this one is too.

Comment: this is vb.net code. i just used the above code as an example its really more like childform.rtbMainText.Text  but i just tried to make it simpler. guess i failed at that lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the text after you put it in and then change the color.

For example:

```
richTextBox1.Text += "Test"
richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.TextLength - 4, 4)
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
```

Comment: This isn't the right way to append a text to any Form control. Each time you are resetting the whole text inside a control which can be very slow when the content gets bigger and bigger. Poor coding.

Answer (score 9):

This code adds text "Hello" in red color and "World" in green to the RichTextBox.

```
RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "Hello "
RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green
RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "World"
```

Comment: Your answer is a lot more straightforward than any of the answers, and it works for me!  Thanks Meta-Knight.

Answer (score 2):

Ive worked with it in VB6 and i think its the same:
You must select the text and then apply

```
this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
```

The added text always appears in the defaut color, you must select it and then change its color:

```
this.richTextBox1.text="Hello world!"
this.richTextBox1.selstart=0
this.richTextBox1.sellength=5
this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
```

As i dont use vb.net, you must check the spelling but i think thats the key.
The code i wrote is supposed to print "Hello" in red and "World!" in black.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    RichTextBox2.SelectionLength = 0
    RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0
    ' We deselect everything first in case the user has something selected.
    RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
    RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "Hello "
    RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green
    RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "World "
```

This will add it to the start of the textbox. I think you could also make SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.TextLength which would put it at the end instead of the start.

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't work:

```
this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
this.richTextBox1.text += "Test"
```

Change the second line to this:

```
this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
this.richTextBox1.selectedtext = "Test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub colorWord(ByVal word As String, ByVal color As Color) ' by im4dbr0
        For i As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.TextLength
            Try
                If RichTextBox1.Text.ElementAt(i).ToString = word.ElementAt(0).ToString Then
                    Dim found As Boolean = False
                    For j As Integer = 1 To word.Count - 1
                        If RichTextBox1.Text.ElementAt(i + j) = word.ElementAt(j) Then
                            found = True
                        Else
                            found = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    If found = True Then
                        RichTextBox1.Select(i, word.Length)
                        RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = color
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Continue For
            End Try
        Next
```

For multiple words use loop

```
 Dim Words As New List(Of String)
        Words.Add("Its")
        Words.Add("That")
        Words.Add("Simple")
        For i As Integer = 0 To Words.Count - 1
            colorWord(Words.Item(i), Color.Red)
        Next
```